# How to get pose of other model from another model plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

How can I get pose of an object from another model plugin? In my model plugin I can get properties of the model I am at easily, but how can pose info of another model except subscring to /gazebo/default/pose/info [which is what I am currenltly doing?

Best regards,
C.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25112/how-to-get-pose-of-other-model-from-another-model-plugin/) by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2020-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use following lines to get the pointer to the other model.

```
physics::WorldPtr world_ptr = model_ptr->GetWorld();

physics::ModelPtr other_model_ptr = world_ptr->ModelByName("other_model_name")
```

Now you can work with the other model the same way as with the model to which the plugin is attached.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2